# How to generate symbol combinations?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have input `char[][]`. I need to generate possible combinations, where each char array provides symbol for correspond position. for example:

```
    char[][] symbols = new char[][] {
            {'M', 'm'},
            {'o', '0'},
            {'i', 'l', '|', 'e'},
            {'s', '$'}
    };
```

using this input data should be generated :

```
Mois
Moi$
Mols
Mol$
MoLs
...
m0e$
```

I've got trouble how to make condition in arrays to update correct symbol from correct array and build than string.

Comment: Look for "cartesian product"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a very unsmooth but working solution using for loops:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
    char[][] symbols = new char[][] { { 'M', 'm' }, { 'o', '0' }, { 'i', 'l', '|', 'e' }, { 's', '$' } };
    String s = "1234";
    for (int i = 0; i < symbols[0].length; i++) {
        s = s.replace(s.charAt(0), symbols[0][i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < symbols[1].length; j++) {
            s = s.replace(s.charAt(1), symbols[1][j]);
            for (int k = 0; k < symbols[2].length; k++) {
                s = s.replace(s.charAt(2), symbols[2][k]);
                for (int l = 0; l < symbols[3].length; l++) {
                    s = s.replace(s.charAt(3), symbols[3][l]);
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

as you can see, this will grow rapidly depending on how long you string will be in the end. therefore other solutions suit it much better. i would highly recommend using @alirabiee answer

Answer (score 3):

You may do this by defining a computer function as below:

```
void compute(String combo, Integer i) {
    if ( i == symbols.length ) {
        System.out.println( combo );
    }
    else {
        for ( int j = 0; j < symbols[ i ].length; j++ ) {
            compute( combo + symbols[ i ][ j ], i + 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your symbols array also needs to be class field, otherwise you need to change it a bit. Then you may call it to print the combinations as below:

```
this.compute( "", 0 );
```